# Crashes in external Microsoft DLL?

Tags: debugging, winapi, visual-c++

I have been battling a crash that occurs in my game engine for about 6 months now. I have recently received a few memory dumps from a tester who gets the crashes (I don't get them myself). The tester is on Windows 7 32 bit, and I am on Windows Xp 32 bit. The crashes seem to be related to Sapi, the text-to-speech part to be more exact. I am calling it via the IDispatch interface, using the wrapper found at:
http://www.morearty.com/code/dispatch/

Here are two stack traces extracted from two memory dumps.

http://www.blastbay.com/analysis1.txt

http://www.blastbay.com/analysis2.txt

The crash shown in the first stack trace occurred at random during the game's execution as it seems, and for some reason the entire stack is not resolved even though perilous_hearts.pdb is certainly present. In the second trace, it is finding the perilous_hearts symbols just fine. I am completely clueless as to what this error might be caused by. Can anyone give me some hints?

As I mentioned before, these crashes do not occur on Windows XP but only on Windows 7, both being 32 bit machines.

Comment: Different crashes, same cause: heap corruption.  The crash location never has anything to do with the code that actually corrupted the heap.  Use Application Verifier to try to find the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases that crash is caused by hlas.dll, whatever that is. As the analysis says, you have heap corruption in the first stack, and a null pointer function pointer in the second. Hlas is also present in your [other question about crashes in this same program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970655/breakpoint-exceptions-from-windows-dlls-on-windows-7).

Comment: I have tried to use Application Verifier but with no results thus far. The crashes don't occur on my development machine, and my tester gets no results (at least not yet). I have no idea what Hlas.dll is, unfortunately.

Comment: You can ask your tester what HLAS.DLL is, maybe the file version information will be a clue. A little Web searching suggests that it's a product by a Czech company called GALOP.

Comment: The dll is apparently a Czech tts voice for Sapi 4, so I have no idea why it's even involved, but I will investigate further and write back here again as soon as I know more. Thank you!

Comment: My tester was using a screen reader for the blind that apparently hooks itself into external processes, and Hlas.dll was not only a Sapi 4 voice but also powered a Sapi 5 engine that his screen reader was using at the time. This dll is known to be unstable apparently, and so if that crashes, the screen reader and the game will go along with it. This is what I have been able to gather. Does it sound like a possible cause?

Comment: I don't think I need to respond to this. You answered your own question